# How to access to Network calls on Chrome in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, cypress

This path is not working ////

I want to access here

[image]

```js
describe('Second GA Tracking', () => {
  it('should be called', () => {
    cy.server();
    // cy.fixture('cypress/fixture/fixture.json').as('@getSecondGA');
    cy.visit(chps.url);
    cy.wait('UA-5883199-36').then((img) => {
      assert.isNotNull(img.response.body.data, 'Second GA Tracking call has data');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: 1- Ctrl+Shift+I (console)
2- choose network tab(2 tabs after console) 
3- type something in Filter text field

Comment: I applied this https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Testing-Strategies on my test, but it's not working

Comment: take a look to the image I addressed, then do first comment steps, please

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `cy.route()` call.  Try this:

```
describe('Second GA Tracking', () => {
  it('should be called', () => {
    cy.server();
    cy.route('**UA-5883199-36**').as('getRequest');
    cy.visit(chps.url);
    cy.wait('@getRequest').then(request => {
      assert.isNotNull(request.response.body.data, 'Second GA Tracking call has data');
    });
  });
});
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html